# How to group each 2 column together and chage the separator type between them?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Input:

```
echo "1021,fra,1022,eng,1023,qad" | sed or awk ...
```

Expected output:

```
1021-fra,1022-eng,1023-gad
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about of waiting for answer only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "1021,fra,1022,eng,1023,qad" |sed 's/\([^,][^,]*\),\([^,][^,]*\)/\1-\2/g'
1021-fra,1022-eng,1023-qad
```

Comment: Your command is very flexible even when i modified the fields contents still working as expected. I can say you in french : "Chapeau Mr Shellter"
echo "1021a,3fra,T1022,4eng,1023,5qad" | sed 's/\([^,][^,]*\),\([^,][^,]*\)/\1-\2/g'
output: 1021a-3fra,T1022-4eng,1023-5qad   Work

Comment: @user3072470 in addition to saying "Chapeau Mr Shellter", you can also upvote him ;-)

Comment: Of course i upvote him now, "Chapeau" for you too for your comment.

Comment: Janos can you please repost your solution maybe it will serve for a nother person. Thanks.

Comment: Could be abbreviated to `sed -r 's/([^,]+),([^,]+)/\1-\2/g'` with GNU sed (and others?).

Comment: @janos, I agree with O.P. Your's is a useful solution in many cases. Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton : yep, less typing is always good ;-). I'm never sure what OS etc OP is  using, so I go with what I *think* is a plain vanilla solution. and BMW seems to have that covered. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

by GNU sed

```
echo "1021,fra,1022,eng,1023,qad"  |sed -r 's/([^,]+),([^,]+)/\1-\2/g'
```

Comment: Why is this `gnu sed`?  Seems to work fine on my old `busybox sed`

Comment: Because I test by GNU Sed only. No time to test in mac, solaris or other sed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, with a little cheat:

```
echo "1021,fra,1022,eng,1023,qad" | sed -e 's/,\([a-z]\)/-\1/g'
```

That is, replace every comma followed by a letter with a hyphen followed by that letter.

In case it helps, here's another version cheating a bit differently:

```
echo "1021,fra,1022,eng,1023,qad" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\),/\1-/g'
```

That is, replace every digit followed by a comma with that digit and a hyphen.

Comment: thanks Janos, i'm looking to group each two columns not based on the contents of each one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
echo "1021,fra,1022,eng,1023,qad" | awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,(i%2?"-":",");print $NF}'
1021-fra,1022-eng,1023-qad
```